# 'thrust::system::system_error' error when running GPGPU database engine Alenka

Tags: gpgpu

I am trying to run alenka (https://github.com/antonmks/Alenka) by loading a custom table test.tbl and fire select queries on it.

It works fine with 3 or 4 rows.
But when I increase number of entries beyond 6 or 10 rows, it does not show any error while loading(./alenka load_test.sql), however when i run query(./alenka testquery.sql), it gives an error:
**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'thrust::system::system_error' what(): invalid argument Aborted (core dumped)**

```
---test.tbl---
1|2.12345|3|4|5|6|7|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|
```

This is the load_test.sql query

```
A := LOAD 'test.tbl' USING ('|') AS (var1{1}:int, var2{2}:int, var3{4}:int,
  var4{5}:int,var5{6}:int, var6{7}:int, var7{8}:int);
  STORE A INTO 'test' BINARY;
```

And testquery.sql

```
B := FILTER test BY id <= 19980902;
D := SELECT var2 AS var2
FROM B;
STORE D INTO 'mytest.txt' USING ('|');
```

Can someone explain, what is the reason for such error?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was raised due to minor errors which summed up to this confusion. 
When a load command is fired on alenka, it creates binary files containing data from each column of the table. 
These files will be overwritten if they are load again, however if the column names are changed it would create a new file along side the old ones.
So its a good idea to delete those files after renaming columns in a table in-order to avoid using them again.

Hence, I got this error because I had loaded data with different column names earlier and forgot to delete those files( test.id*) files from its folder. 
Along with that, I also committed one more blunder of filtering it with "id" instead of 'var1' in query(testquery.sql) file.

Since the id files had 9 entries(from the previous schema), it ran perfectly for 9 rows but when the database size increased beyond that ,the thrust library threw system error.

Hope this helps someone from wasting time like I did.